# Identity of electronics component needed

Tags: components

I can not figure what the white colored component labeled "5W3K9J" is. The "3K" part seems to indicate a 3K resistor. Could some one please verify this?

[image]

Answer (score 11):

It's a wirewound resistor and the breakdown would be:

- 5W is the power rating
- 3K9 indicates a 3.9 kΩ resistance
- J is the 5% tolerance code, see this [Wikipedia table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistor#Industrial_type_designation)

Answer (score 6):

5W is the power rating - 5 watts

3K9 is the value - 3900 Ω

J is a [tolerance indicator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistor#Industrial_type_designation) - ±5%